# How to cascade jQuery Mobile combo boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have developed a cascading select menu that updates combo boxes that has the same value.

I have trouble in updating multiple combo boxes. For example, I managed to cascade a parent combo box to its child(a) combo box. But the I want child(b) etc. to update dynamically.

The solution I have thought of is create separate functions for the 3 combo boxes, and whenever anyone of them is changed it will update. Of course, each parent has its own child (matching value), therefore changing the child combo boxes will not affect the parent.

Here's what I have wrote: https://jsfiddle.net/1ospxyer/6/ (Please load it in JQuery mobile in JSFiddle - left side)

```
var storeSiteList = $("#select-choice-1>option");
var storeBuildingList = $("#select-choice-2>option");
var storeLocationList = $("#select-choice-3>option");

function siteFilter() {
    $("#select-choice-1").change(function () {
        $("#select-choice-2").append(storeBuildingList);
        var current_site = $(this).val();
        $("#select-choice-2>option").each(function () {
            if (current_site !== $(this).val()) {
                $(this).remove();
                $("#select-choice-2").selectmenu("refresh");
            }
        });

    });
}

function buildingFilter() {
    $("#select-choice-2").change(function () {
        $("#select-choice-3").append(storeLocationList);
        var current_building = $(this).val();
        $("#select-choice-3>option").each(function () {
            if (current_building !== $(this).val()) {
                $(this).remove();
                $("#select-choice-3").selectmenu("refresh");
            }
        });
    });
}

function locationFilter() {
    $("#select-choice-3").change(function () {
        $("#inputFloor").val($(this).val());
    });
}

siteFilter();
buildingFilter();
locationFilter();
```

Is there a way to cascade multiple combo boxes (more than just the first two)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just trigger the change event on the child combo after you update it so that the third combo will be updated.

```
$("#select-choice-1").change(function () {
    $("#select-choice-2").append(storeBuildingList);
    var current_site = $(this).val();
    $("#select-choice-2>option").each(function () {
        if (current_site !== $(this).val()) {
            $(this).remove();
            $("#select-choice-2").selectmenu("refresh");
        }
    });
    //trigger change
    $("#select-choice-2").change();
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/1ospxyer/8/)**

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know you can use change function like that. I always thought you must declare something inside for it to work. Learnt something new :)

Similarly, can you do this with other functions? Like click, keyup?

Comment: @Newtonic, it is just shorthand for trigger():  http://api.jquery.com/trigger/.  So, yes you can trigger any event.

Comment: This works fine with Android devices, but only the next child is updated on iPhone. I noticed iPhone uses scroll select, rather than clickable options like Android. Do you know what method to resolve this issue? Thanks again.

Comment: @Newtonic, are you saying the change event does not fire on iOS?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I revamped my code and realised it was the speed factor that causing the code not to execute correctly. Now it is working fine. Thanks once again.